# Vue.js + Axios разница в производительности между async/await и promises

Tags: vue.js, axios

Есть ли разница в коде( с точки зрения производительности и в любой другой ) между кодом:

```
async fetchAllCategories(){

  const response = await this.$axios.get(
    "https://hplussport.com/api/products/categories"
  );

  console.log(response);

},
```

и кодом:

```
async fetchAllCategories(){

  axios.get("https://hplussport.com/api/products/categories")
    .then(response => (console.log(response)))

},
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет, синтаксический сахар и личное предпочтение и удобство чтения!)